# »mal wieder« vs. »wieder«

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference or nuance between the two sentences?

> Ich habe *mal* wieder Kopfschmerz.
>   Ich habe wieder Kopfschmerz.

I am not sure what is the »mal« trying to point out here.

Answer (score 8):

this is one of these subtle German expressions :)
In this case, "mal" (short for "einmal" =once) expresses that the speaker has frequently headache (by the way, it's "Kopfschmerzen", plural). "Wieder" without "mal" only says that the speaker has had headache before. I would say it roughly translates to "I have headache again" vs "Once again I have headache".

You are right, it's a nuance but significant.
Similar  cases are
"Das Haus ist schön" (the house is nice) vs "das Haus ist ja schön" (wow, this house is quite nice)
"Draußen ist es dunkel" (it's dark outside) vs. "draußen ist es doch dunkel" (but it's dark outside)

Comment: +1; instead of *mal wieder* one could drop in *wieder einmal*. The latter is considered exalted speaking, though. *Der HSV hat mal wieder im letzten Spiel die Kurve gekriegt.* (tv commentator on the last HSV game of the season) vs. *Wieder einmal hat der HSV sich selbst im letzten Spiel vor dem Abstieg gerettet.* (newspaper on the same topic)

Comment: @Janka HSV? Please explain!

Comment: @Beta: HSV = [Hamburger Sport-Verein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_SV); well known as soccer club.

Comment: HSV is a German soccer club which always played first league, from the beginning, but in the last years was hardly able to maintain that score.

Comment: "mal wieder" can have different connotations. There's the annoyed connotation in for example "Maria kann heute nicht arbeiten. Sie hat mal wieder 'Kopfschmerzen'." ("Maria can't work today. She's yet again got a 'headache'.") And there's the more neutral connotation in for example "Ich muss mal wieder den Keller aufräumen" (roughly "I have to straighten up the basement again sometime soon").

Comment: Glad to this answer, dustfinga, as I was also confused by "mal" in such contexts. (By the way, in English we would say "I have a headache" instead of just "I have headache".)

Answer (score 0):

"Mal wieder" is short for *ein* mal wieder. It has the connotations not only "again," but "Here's *another* one," with the previous one being recent, or in the not-too-distant past.

"Wieder" means "again," and refers to something that has happened in the "past," but not as part of a "pattern" or "connection" as in the first paragraph.